# Validating string numbers with negative sign using asp range validation

Tags: c#, asp.net, validation

Hi and thanks in advance,

I have a some latitudes and longitudes that look something like this:  **-81.7426684 W  - -81.6901007 W** that I am trying to validate using asp rangevalidation using the minimum and maximum values attributes.

asp:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtLon" runat="server" CssClass="container-input-field" SkinID="NumTextUpDown"></asp:TextBox>
 <asp:RangeValidator ID="RangeLong_Validator" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtLon"
                                CssClass="errorMessage" ToolTip="Longitude Out Of Range" Type="String">
                                <img alt="" src="images/no.png" />
                            </asp:RangeValidator>
```

c#:

```
RangeLong_Validator.MinimumValue = "" + getCompassLon(range.LowLong); // -81.7426684 W

        RangeLong_Validator.MaximumValue = "" + getCompassLon(range.HighLong); // -81.7426684 W

        rangeSetUp_Lon.Text = RangeLong_Validator.MinimumValue + " - " + RangeLong_Validator.MaximumValue;
```

I get this error:  **System.Web.HttpException: The MaximumValue -81.6901007 W cannot be less than the MinimumValue -81.7426684 W of RangeLong_Validator.** I think its not counting the negative sign.

I have to using strings because I might have a formats that looks like this as well: **25 32' 13.2" E, 124 59.94' E**

I am up for any ideas.

Comment: swap your low and high values - do you still get the error?

Comment: @geedubb no I don't get the error, but that wouldn't be the correct bounds for the min. & max. values

Answer (score 0):

In general, when using RangeValidator for numbers, you should specify Type="Integer" or Type="Double", but not Type="String".

However, in your specific case the subject data is more complicated than just a number - it has " W" at the end, and as you mentioned the format could be even more complicated.
Therefore, in order to properly validate such data you should use CustomValidator. This way you'll be able to parse the data and test it against any rules.

Comment: Lets say I removed the letter, and use one of the other formats: **-25 32' 13.2"**, I still could not use rangevalidation right?

Comment: RangeValidator knows nothing about that format with degrees, minutes and seconds, it can handle only integer and floating-point numbers.

Comment: Does the asp custom validation only use javascript or can I do c# as well? Also I could removed the quotes if necessary, but then I would have something like this: **-25 32 13.2**, but I am sure how it would handle those spaces.

Comment: Custom validation can be done both on the server (c#) and in the browser (javascript).